# Fancybox 3 setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox, fancybox-3

I would like an internal URL to fire in Fancybox 3 around 5 seconds once the page has loaded. I have the following code however I just get loading PNG - nothing appears.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $.fancybox.open({
    iframe : {
      href:'http://www.gamespot.com'
      }
    });
  }, 2000);
```

I'm not very smart with JS, though I believe it may clashing with some other code. Any advice before this Mac goes out the window?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out samples from the documentation - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api
and use correct syntax, something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $.fancybox.open({
    type : 'iframe',
    src  : 'https://codepen.io/spark/',
    opts : {
      iframe : {
        preload : false
      }
    }
  });
}, 2000);
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooBZoK?editors=1010

btw, you will not be able to include gamespot.com, because this site (like many others) prevents embedding.

Comment: Mate, I owe you a beer. Thanks!

Comment: Done :) I actually have another question which I'll post now.